# How identify shapes drawn with Core Graphics in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-graphics, swift2

I'm creating a project in Swift that draws some shapes, based on [this tutorial](https://www.weheartswift.com/bezier-paths-gesture-recognizers/). My project involves some things to most, like removing the shape drawn on the View.
To begin need to recognize them in layers, or uniquely identify what form should remove.

I'm working on it just over two weeks, but I'm running out of idea what to do.

My question:
How can I identify and separate shapes drawn with Core Graphics in Swift?

Comment: You cannot "recognize" or "identify" anything. You (your code) drew the shapes; if you need to know later where and what they are, it is up to you to keep track of them at the time you draw them. That is how any drawing program works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way:

```
for layer in self.view.layer.sublayers! {
    print(layer)
}
```

I can get all layers drawing in my view.